# TYPO3 tx_news entries within a date range

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I am currently migrating tt_news to news. The old news system also has news-entries shown as events. Is it somehow possible to hide entries that are past, without having to archive those? Or else to show only entries within the next x days?

This was possible with tt_news typoscript:

```
extensions.ttnews_selectconf {
    andWhere (
        tt_news.datetime < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() +604800)
        AND tt_news.datetime > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400)
    )
}
```

I could not find anything in the news docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The news extension has a TypoScript option to set a minimum date/time: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#timerestriction

So `plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction = now` will show news items starting now. `plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction = today` will show news items starting at the start of today.

For a maximum date you can use `timeRestrictionHigh`

Also, if you're using news for events, you might want to check out the eventnews extension. This extends the news extension to add fields and views that are useful for events. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/eventnews

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any possibility to have "per Plugin" settings? Both the news and the events are listed on one page and I cannot place the Typoscript directly onto that page.